# Ingress not working with cloudflare proxy option

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, kubernetes, cloudflare, nginx-ingress

I have cloudflare on it added A record of haproxy loadbalancer, behind loadbalancer are worker nodes of kubernetes cluster and ingress controller.

Ingress routing traffic good when proxy option on CloudFlare on A record is disable as soon I enable proxy option on CloudFlare it will stop working and I will get only default cloud flare page in browser..

Anyone know what is issue?

Comment: It sounds like CloudFlare isn't passing along, or setting, the `host:` header, which the Ingress controller uses to route within the cluster

Comment: What does the cloudflare page say? It usually it gives language helping to indicate the issue, usually something like an ssl failure or a failure to connect to the origin server.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue.